# Xamarin.Forms: Add items to ListView from codebehind without binding?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

So far I've added a map and a `listview` with static items to my Form. This is what the `xaml` looks like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200"
        x:Name="MyMap"
        IsShowingUser="true"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>dog</x:String>
                    <x:String>cat</x:String>
                    <x:String>bird</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Instead of being static items, I would like to add them using a simple `foreach` loop. This is what the loops looks like:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] pets = { "dog", "cat", "bird" };
        foreach (string pet in pets)
        {
            /* Add each pet to ListView */
            //ListView_Pets.ItemsSource.Add(pet); This doesn't build
        }
    }
```

I was looking at [ListView Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding), but they declare a collection  `ObservableCollection` that I then bind to the `ListView`. I don't want to bind my ListView to a collection; I'm looking for the equivalent of this `asp.net` snippet (if it's possible):

```
foreach (string name in nameList)
{
    DropDownList_Pets.Items.Add(new ListItem(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just assign your array to `ItemsSource`

```
string[] pets = { "dog", "cat", "bird" };
ListView_Pets.ItemsSource = pets;
```

any `IEnumerable` can be used as an `ItemsSource`